# Passing value of variable inside a string using C

Tags: c, string

Suppose i have a string `const char *temp = "i am new to C"`.

Now i have a float variable `a=1.0000;`

How can i send the value of "a" inside `const char *temp` along with the existing string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick pointer: You can't do: `char *temp = "i am new to C"`. You need to do `char temp[] = "i am new to C"`.

Comment: Please your real words related to programming. "sending along" and "inside" may sound good in a speech, but it's totally vague and unclear in the context of this question.

Comment: @Mystical - offtopic but ... erm, yes, you can. It's called a string literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted a string to include the value of a variable you could use snprintf;

```
char temp[100];
float a =1.00;
sprintf(temp,"The Value of a is %f", a);
printf("%s", temp);
```

This would print "The Value of a is 1.00"

Answer (score 1):

```
const char temp[] = "I am new to C";
float a = 1.0;
char buffer[256];
sprintf(buffer, "%s %f", temp, a);
```